# Why does this function return a value when there is no call to return?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following example in my book, which is supposed to be a program whch calculates the new balance after interest is added on multiple accounts:

```
def addInterest(balances, rate):
    for i in range (len(balances)):
    balances[i] = balances[i] * (1 + rate)


def test():
    amounts = [1000, 2200, 800, 360]
    rate = 0.05
    addInterest(amounts, rate)
    print(amounts)


test()
```

The output is [1050.0, 2310.0, 840.0, 378.0]

There is no return call at the end of addInterest, so 
why doesn't print(amounts) just print amounts which was defined intially, namely [1000, 2200, 800, 360]?

Comment: What is the given output? What is the given return?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Sorry I just added the output of the program

Comment: I don't get it. You printed the result, what is the problem?

Comment: This is not an example of returning a value. Lists are mutable [see explanation here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) so when you call the function `addInterest`, it _actually changes_ the values in `amounts`. The changed value is what gets printed

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I don't understand why the output isn't [1000, 2200, 800, 360], because there is no call for return in addInterest

Comment: Because you index the function and reassign the value at the given index.

Comment: Python arguments are [pass by (object) reference](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, when no return is specified, `None` is returned by default. But, why are you getting other values? Because when you do this

```
balances[i] = balances[i] * (1 + rate)
```

you are modifying the values of the list `balances`.

So, you are doing the following:

1. Declare the list `amounts = [1000, 2200, 800, 360]`
2. Call the function `addInterest` passing the list as a parameter. Inside this function you are modifying the content of this list. You don't return anything, but the list is already modified.
3. You print the modified list and the new values are shown.

Comment: But if amounts was just defined as a number, (i.e. amounts = 1000) then the print statement would display 1000, not 1050

Comment: Note that between the definition and the `print` there is a call to `addInterests`. You are passing your list `amount` to `addInterests` and in this function this list is modified. Finally, when you reach the `print` the list `amount` has the new values.

Comment: @so if amount is a mutable object, the print statement would show the modified amount; and if amount is a non-mutable object, then the print statement would show the non-modified ammount?

Comment: The `print` statement just prints the content, nothing else. What matters here is if you modify the object or not. In this case, a `list` is mutable, but for example, a `tuple` isn't. You won't be able to modify a `tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not return anything, but it prints the result. If you just do :

```
def test():
    amounts = [1000, 2200, 800, 360]
    rate = 0.05
    addInterest(amounts, rate)
```

then `test()` will be None (which is the default return value of a function).

If you want your function to return a result, you have to change the print to a return like this :

```
def test():
    amounts = [1000, 2200, 800, 360]
    rate = 0.05
    addInterest(amounts, rate)
    return amount
```

Also, be careful when modifying a list in a function. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/17686659/4709400

Answer (score 1):

Because lists are mutable and `balances[i] = balances[i] * (1 + rate` modified the values of `amounts` too, which was passed with the call `addInterest(amounts, rate)`

Thus `addInterest()` has an implicit return value in this case.

Answer (score 1):

See this post about [data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) and in particular the part about mutability.

Here is an example of how lists are mutable

```
>>> arr = [1,2,3]
>>> arr[0] = 99
>>> print(arr)
[99, 2, 3]
```

When you call the `addInterest` function, passing the `amounts` array as a parameter, it modified that array. Here's another example showing how that occurs

```
def test(my_list):
    print(my_list)
    my_list[0] = 99
    print(my_list)
```

Now test in the interpreter

```
>>> arr = [1,2,3]
>>> x = test(arr)
[1,2,3] 
[99, 2, 3]
>>> arr
[99,2,3]
>>> x
>>> x is None
True
```

So you can see, the return value of the function is `None`, which we stored in the variable named `x`. But the function also has a *side effect*, which is to change the value of the list `arr` that was passed into it.

Finally, let's see an example like yours, where the array is defined inside a function.

```
def change_list(l):
    print(l)
    l[0] = 99
    print(l)


def test():
    arr = [1,2,3]
    change_list(arr)
```

and check it out in the interpreter

```
>>> x = test()
[1, 2, 3]
[99, 2, 3]
>>> x
>>> x is None
True
```

Hope this clears up any confusion.