# changing elements of a list vs changing the list itself

Tags: python, variables, scope

I have a question about the name scope of variables, I've tried to find the answer here and I got a similar one but still little confused here
[Function changes list values and not variable values in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686596/function-changes-list-values-and-not-variable-values-in-python)

So the code is as follows:

```
position = [50, 50]

# Handler for timer
def tick():
    x = random.randrange(0, width)
    y = random.randrange(0, height)
    position[0] = x
    position[1] = y
```

Here why don't I need to add "global position" in order to change elements of the variable position?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `global position` would only be necessary if you were assigning the global *position* variable to refer to a new list (without the *global* declaration, *position* would written into the locals for the function).

In your situation, all you are doing is looking up the global variable *position* to find which list it refers to.  Then you're updating that list in-place.

Here is a [Python tutor visualization](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=position_a+%3D+%5B50,+50%5D%0Aposition_b+%3D+%5B66,+66%5D%0Aposition_c+%3D+%5B99,+99%5D%0A%0Adef+tick(%29%3A%0A++++global+position_c%0A++++position_b+%3D+%5B77,+77%5D%0A++++position_a%5B0%5D+%3D+55%0A++++position_b%5B0%5D+%3D+88%0A++++position_c+%3D+%5B11,+11%5D%0A%0Atick(%29%0A++++&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=11) that shows all the variations (assign to a local, assign to a global, update a list referred to by a global).

Also, have a look at Ned Batchelder's [nice blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) that fully explains python's pass-by-object mechanism.

Comment: so you mean here the elements of position is automatically updated without the necessity of declaring it as global? I'm kinda struggling to accept this concept...

Comment: Yes.  Think of it this way.  Imagine you have a global variable called *position* that is a connection to a database.  You can lookup that variable without a *global* declaration (because there is no local of the same name). Then you can use that connection to modify the database but no change the connection itself.  When would need a *global* declaration?  Only if you were assigning a new connection to *position*.  In the first case, *position* remains unchanged and database changes.  In the second case, *position* is changed to a different connection.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I know the cod that I provided initially was of which case?

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation of *Naming and Binding*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) -

> If a variable is used in a code block but **not defined there**, it is a free variable.

From the [documentation of global statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) -

> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals. It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, **although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global.**

(Emphasis mine)

When you do -

```
position[0] = <something>
```

You are not *defining* anything, you are mutating the already *defined list* `position` inplace (changing its 0th element to refer to something else) .

Lets assume if `position` was not defined ever, when you do something like -

```
position[0] = 1
```

You will get `NameError` -

```
>>> position[0] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'position' is not defined
```

That is why, even though you do `postion[0] = <something>` , its still a free variable, as its not defined in the block, and hence it is treated as global.

---

**UPDATE** :

More info , when you do -

```
position[0] = <something>
```

This is not a [simple `assignment` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) , its actually an [augmented assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements) .

Comment: so you mean here the elements of position is automatically updated without the necessity of declaring it as global? I'm kinda struggling to accept this concept...

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply two concepts for understanding your code

- Python Object Model
- Scoping

**First the Scoping Rules:**

Following are hierarchy of Scoping Rules for Variables

1. Local Scope -   Inside the function
2. Enclosing   -   Inside any or all of Enclosing Function
3. Global      -   Top Level Module ( File )
4. Built In's  -   Any BuiltIn Modules which are being imported

**Python Object Model :**

In Python, everything is a object.
When an variable is declared say `x = 1000`, following steps happens

- int object with Value 1000 is created
- object reference `x` is created
- `x` is pointed to that integer object

Now, when statement `position[0] = x` is executed inside `tick()` , the statement doesn't have initialization part only assignment. Since `position` is not defined inside function scope, it looks for in order of Hierarchy of Scoping Rules - the Enclosing Scope (Parent Function) followed by Module Scope ( File ) followed by BuiltIn Modules. Over here it finds the variable in Global scope and updates it.

In-case your statement is `position = [100, 100]` , a new list object is created and new object reference is created within scope of tick() function and performs the assignment

If you have `global position` statement, it tells Python that variable in Global Scope is same as variable in Local Scope. This followed by `position = [100,100]` creates a list object `[100,100]` and links it global variable `position` to the new list object.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still a little confused here, so you say when I do "position[0] = x" the object position is available in global scope, I agree with that, but when I do "position = [100, 100]", isn't object position still available in global scope? How come it creates a new object?

Comment: @Enkri_  , when `position = [100,100]` is executed both initialization & assignment occurs. so position is defined in local scope and assignment occurs. When `position[0] = x` is executed only assignment happens. There is no initialization , it starts searching in order of hierarchy of scoping rules, finds a match in Global scope and updates it.  I have updated my answer to reflect the same,