# def loop only change list in local scope

Tags: python, list, function, methods, scope

In Python 3, I want to define a function that takes in a list *a*, does some operations and then returns some property of *a*.
The problem is that **I want *a* to stay unchanged.**

Take for example the following code

```py
def test(a):
    a.remove(1)
    return max(a)
```

When I run this, I get:

```py
>>> b = [0,1,2,3]
>>> test(b)
3
>>> b
[0,2,3]
```

whereas I want **b** to stay unchanged

```py
>>> b
[0,1,2,3]
```

I find this rather confusing, as Python does leave floats, ints, ... unchanged when being passed to a function. 
Can anyone please explain what's going on? And what should I do to avoid this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The difference is that floats and ints are immutable whereas list is not

Comment: Assignment is not mutation; `b = [1]` is very different from `b.append(1)`.

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686596/function-changes-list-values-and-not-variable-values-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `list.remove` method alters the list in-place. If you don't want the given list to change you can make a copy of the list first instead:

```
def test(a):
    a = a[:]
    a.remove(1)
    return max(a)
```