# why cant i get the result in the first function in the code below but have no issues getting them in the second one?

Tags: python, function

Function 1

```
def scale(data, factor):
    for j in data:
        j = j * factor

target = [1,2,3,4,5]
factors = 4

scale(target, factors)
print(target)
```

Output = `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Function 2

```
def scale(data, factor):
    for j in range(len(data)):
        data[j] *= factor

target = [1,2,3,4,5]
factors = 4

scale(target, factors)
print(target)
```

Output `[4, 8, 12, 16, 20]`

Why is it that in the first function i dont get the output but when i use the range function i suddenly do?

Comment: `data[j] *= factor` is `data[j] =data[j]* factor` will you use `__setitem__` which will set item in place.

Comment: [Function changes list values and not variable values in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686596/function-changes-list-values-and-not-variable-values-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the way you are accessing those arrays. The in the first case

```
for j in data:
    j = j * factor
```

You access each `j <int>` in data. Since in Python, variables of type `int` are immutable, by doing `j = j * factor`, you make a new variable called `j` with new memory, the old `j` is still referenced by 'data', but the old `j`'s memory did not change here. Crucially, `data` is still referencing the old `j`, so it does not change.

In contrast, when doing

```
for j in range(len(data)):
    data[j] =  data[j] * factor # <- equivalent to *=
```

You get a pointer to the j-th element of `data`, multiply it's value by `factor`, and set`data[j]` to be that new value.